# vue file dont working in atom IDE with webpack

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-component

I'm creating a project in Rails with vue, for this I'm working with webpack, what happens and my text editor, atom IDE, does not process the .vue files, I've tried the steps that the documentation recommends, but I do not know what I'm doing wrong

I provided loading the vue-loader by npm, but I still can not see the .vue files in my project, then I did it by configuring in the webpack.config.js file, and nothing. Then I leave the links of the things I did that did not work.

```
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';
import OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin from '../../../src/';

module.exports = {
   entry: './index',
   module: {
   rules: [
   {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: { loader: 'style-loader' },
      use: {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: { minimize: true }
      }
},
vue: {
loaders: {
     sass: 'style!css!sass?indentedSyntax',
scss: 'style!css!sass'
  }
},
plugins: [
   new ExtractTextPlugin('file.css'),
   new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
    assetNameRegExp: /optimize-me\.css/g
   })
};
```

I hope to be able to work the .vue files

Comment: Do you have Vue itself installed?

Comment: create the proyect with postgresql, then add the webpack gem, its configurations, and then run the commands, npm i vue bootstrap-vue bootstrap and npm install -D vue-loader vue-template-compiler

Comment: yes vue is it installed